# Automate pdf downloads using python

Tags: urllib3

I want to automatically download new pdf files as they are published on a collection of online libraries. I tried using the following python code but found it doesn't work with urllib 3. Anyone know how I can replicate it?

```
import urllib2

def main():
    download_file("http://mensenhandel.nl/files/pdftest2.pdf")

def download_file(download_url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open("document.pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    print("Completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good. I just did a few minor adjustments. The first thing is you need to use the content method of the response. Below is the code -

```
import requests

def main():
    download_file("http://mensenhandel.nl/files/pdftest2.pdf")

def download_file(download_url):
    response = requests.get(download_url, stream = True)
    with open("document.pdf", 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
        file.close()
    print("Completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```